# Why did Poincare's work on relativity remain virtually unnoticed for a long time?

Tags: ho.history-overview

If we inspect the physical literature of the founding period (1905-1918) 
of relativity, we clearly see that Einstein's papers played the major role, while Poincare's ones were left virtually unnoticed (they were cited about five times less frequently). See http://www.chss.uqam.ca/Portals/0/docs/articles/Gingras-EInstein-Poincare.pdf (The Collective Construction of Scientific Memory: The Einstein-Poincare Connection and its Discontents, 1905–2005, by Yves Gingras).

On the other hand, from the modern perspective,  Poincare's treatment of the Lorentz group is extraordinary advanced and modern. So why did his papers have no influence on the development of special relativity? Was he simply far ahead of his time?

Comment: advertisement is discouraged on this site, I think. Even if you advertise your own work.

Comment: I have deleted a link to our paper.

Comment: Poincare has discovered the relativity 5 years before Einstein, but Einstein said he was not aware of Poincare work. In the Russian version of the first paper of Einstein about special relativity, the name of his first wife appears has a coauthor and does not appear in later versions.

Remark that Einstein never received a Nobel prize for his work on relativity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_priority_dispute#Special_relativity

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mileva_Mari%C4%87#Role_in_physics

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/science/across-the-universe/2012/oct/08/einstein-nobel-prize-relativity

Comment: https://www.technologyreview.com/s/427621/did-einsteins-first-wife-secretly-coauthor-his-1905-relativity-paper/

Comment: Poincare framed his group-theoretic perspective as the mathematics of a theory by Lorentz that he expected to fail: "it would suffice to renounce this definition [of lengths as times] for the theory of Lorentz to be as completely overthrown as Ptolemy’s system....If this happens some day, it will not prove that the effort made by Lorentz was useless; for Ptolemy, whatever one thinks of him, was not useless."  So he himself did not appreciate the potential physical significance of his work, which helps explain why others also failed to see it.  See Howard Stein, "Physics and Pholosophy Meet".

Comment: Meanwhile, the question is already answered in the very paper cited in the post, in section 7!